# react-redux: dispatch action from reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'd like to dispatch an action from the BuildingComponent's reducer function to affect the state of the InfoDrawer's state.

I know that this is not possible in redux, but I can't think of an alternative. Can anyone give me any suggestions/recommendations?

Thanks ahead of time. Any help is appreciated.

**BuildingComponent**

```
//BuildingsState initial state
let initialState = {
  hasHighlight: false,
  buildings: [],
  visible: false,
}

// BuildingsState reducer
export function BuildingsState(state = initialState, action) {

  if (action.type === 'BUILDING_TOGGLE') {

    if(state.hasHighlight && state.visible) {

      // I WANT TO DISPATCH AN ACTION HERE
      // dispatch({ type: "ResetPOIs" })

    } else {
      return {
        ...state,
        visible: !state.visible
      }
    }
  }

  ...

}
```

**InfoDrawerComponent**

```
//initial InfoDrawer State
const initialState = {
  open: false,
  textToDisplay: "",
  link: "",
}

//InfoDrawer reducer
export function InfoDrawerState ( state = initialState, action ) {

  if (action.type === "ResetPOIs") {
    return { textToDisplay: "", link: "", open: false };
  }

  ...

}
```

**Here is how my state is laid out**

```
state = {

  BuildingsState: {
    hasHighlight: false,
    buildings: [],
    visible: false
  }

  InfoDrawerState: {
    textToDisplay: "",
    link: "",
    open: false
  }

  ...

}
```

Comment: That's not possible, and that's not how Redux is supposed to work.  What actual end goal are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: If my building layer is on and a building is highlighted, my infoDrawer displays building information. My goal is to have the infoDrawer not display the building information once the building layer is turned off. Right now, the infoDrawer still displays the information after the layer is turned off. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I have done in the past is to use redux-thunk (https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) and dispatch actions from my thunks.  The thunks are evaluated synchronously so you can easily get the state before and after the original action is dispatched.  For example:

```
export const toggleBuilding = () => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        dispatch({type: 'BUILDING_TOGGLE'});

        let {hasHighlight, visible} = getState();

        if(hasHighlight && visible) {
            //dispatch more stuff
        }
    }
};
```

Another alternative is to set up a subscription to your redux store that check for when hasHighlight and visible are set to true.  You can do this from a component using connect(), or a direct subscription.

Comment: This is a nice, clean approach. IMHO, anyone getting into Redux should also be looking into using thunks for better control of state updates.

Comment: oh ya. I've seen redux-thunk before but didn't look too much into it. But it looks like it's exactly what I need. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest having the `infoDrawer` reducer listen to the same action type.  If necessary, have the logic that dispatches the action put the additional info from the buildings state into the action object.  See [the Redux FAQ entry on sharing state between reducers](https://redux.js.org/faq/reducers#how-do-i-share-state-between-two-reducers-do-i-have-to-use-combinereducers) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a middleware that listen on actiontype you want to interact with or you can use redux observable https://redux-observable.js.org/